# Iptables to lock down compromised server to a single ip

Tags: linux, security, iptables, firewall

I have a Linux server which is compromised, I can see nasty looking perl scripts executing with root privileges. I want to get some data off it before I wipe it. How can I block all inbound and outbound traffic except for my ip? It's a Centos server I assume i can do this with iptables?

I'm aware a the server is rooted there is a possibility that attackers could have made changes on the server that would prevent this from working. Ill be testing to make sure and only have the server online for a couple of hours before it is nuked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace X.X.X.X with your IP address and this should work:

```
iptables -I INPUT ! -s X.X.X.X -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT ! -d X.X.X.X -j REJECT
iptables -I FORWARD -j DROP
```

Comment: While this answer may theoretically work you ***SHOULD NOT*** trust any functionality on a compromised server: You have no way of knowing if `iptables` has been affected. You should *physically disconnect the machine from the network*, and grab any data you need from the compromised host using either a crossover cable or a USB stick.

Comment: The above comment is true, although most of the time it should be fairly reasonable mitigation. I've never come across a script kiddie who goes to the trouble of altering netfilter functionality, but there's no guarantee it's a script kiddie who's compromised your box. If you have customers details, credit cards etc on that box, disconnect it. If it's just a web server with minimal sensitive data, you could make the call to just use the above.